# problem on mixture and alligation - mixing water and milk and finding profit percentage

Tags: percentages, word-problem

[image]

I solved it and getting answer as 200%

My calculations are
water: x

milk 2x

cost price: 2x*7=14x

selling price: 3x*7*2=42x

profit : 28x

percentage profit : 28x/14x * 100 = 200%

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is (3) 40%

It's key to realize there are 3 different kinds of mixes here:
1) pure milk
2) milk with water addition
3) mix with water substitution

Let's find the Volumes:
1) 10 L we purchased
2) 16,666% of something is 1/6 of it. So we need to add x water so that W/(W+M)=1/6. Since we know M=10 we solve and get W=2. Now for the next mixture we need to substitute (ie. take out + add) instead of just adding.
So we need to take out x of mixture but also add x of water such that M/W=2.
Since the ratio of milk il 10/12 and of water is 2/12 then we know that taking out x of mixture will reduce the quantity of milk and water by 10/12x and 2/12x respectively.
In math, (10-10/12x)/(2-2/12x+x)=2. Solving we have x=12/5. This is the replaced amount we will sell at double price!
3) Since we substituted this time we still got 12L of mixture

Hence, we will:
1) buy 10L at 7 Rs
2) sale 12/5L at 14 Rs
3) sale 12L at 7 Rs

Profit margin will be (12*7+12/5*14-10*7)/(12*7+12/5*14) which is 40%
QED

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Your answer will be better received if you use MathJax.